# Eclipse seems to think the CSS files are Java source code

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx

I'm using Eclipse Eclipse IDE for Java Developers [Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Build id: 20181214-0600] to develop a JavaFX project but I got some problems.
After a Java update, I've found several errors in my CSS files. Eclipse seems to think the CSS files are Java source code, as figured in the image below.

[image]

When I drag the mouse on a error, the description is "Syntax error on token 'Invalid character', interface expected" (because of # symbol)
I'm sure the code is correct because there are no errors before the latest java update to version 1.8.2.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you post a pastebin of the css file? Do you have any particular reason to keep css files in your source packages instead of resource folder?

Comment: Check your Content Types preference page and see if *.css has actually been added under Java Source File. You might be able to remove it. Also, right-click on the file and make sure you're not opening it with the Java Editor.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely what happened here is what @Gianpio Benincasa said: You've created a new class, then in the file explorer you renamed it.

However, it's worth checking this one: Go to window/preferences, type 'associations' in the filter box to quickly nav to setting General>Editors>File Associations, and scroll through the file types list for *.css. Click on it, and check which editors are associated with it.

An eclipse with no particularly relevant plugins should only list 'Text Editor', and it should be marked as default. If you added plugins specifically for editing CSS, those will also be listed (and one of those is now probably default instead). Perhaps you or someone else went out of their way to add the java editor to this list somehow. If that is the case, simply make 'text editor' the default again (click it, click 'default'), then click on the java editor, and click 'remove'.

Answer (score 0):

for eclipse that is a java class, in fact the icon has the "J". Probably when you created it you have created a new class and then have renamed it.

Create a new generic file instead a java class and copy the contents to the new file.
For create a generic file, rightclick and follow new-> other-> General-> files

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error too. Looks like there is a bug that causes this error. I am able to open the css file by "right clicking" on the css file then select "Open with" then select "Text Editor". From here you can create new css file or open an already existing css file.